# Is there a way to check how many days have passed since the program was last opened - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Is there a way in Python to save the date the program was opened and then check when it was opened and how many days it has been since then?

For example say I run the program on the 7th of May 2018 and then run it again on the 14th of May 2018 is there a way to tell that 7 days have passed and assign that number of days to a variable?

Comment: Before running the program, you can look at when the file was accessed last, but when you've started the program, it's too late because you have accessed it again. But you can write the current date to a file when finishing and then look at that file when you run again, unless the user has done something silly with it.

Comment: Pretty simple. Write the latest date your script was run to a external text file, read that date in when your script is run a second time, and compare that date to the current date.

Comment: Just do exactly what you want -- `1` save the date (which contains 2 sub-questions `a` get the date and `b` save to a file), and `2` check the data (which again contains `a` read a file `b` get current date `c` find difference). In summary, probably too broad.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Here is a version that should work out of the box:

```
import configparser
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

config = configparser.ConfigParser()

config.read('dates.ini')
try:
    last = (datetime.strptime(config['Dates']['last'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
except KeyError:
    last = datetime.today()

cfgfile = open("./dates.ini",'w')
try:
    config.add_section('Dates')
except configparser.DuplicateSectionError:
    pass
config.set('Dates','last',str(datetime.today()))
config.write(cfgfile)
cfgfile.close()

print((last - datetime.today()).days)
```

Comment: If the program runs for several days, it may be more interesting when it finished last.

Comment: Possibly, though the question did specify 'when opened'. But to do something on exit, I would assume you would just need something like: `import atexit` and `atexit.register(myfunction)` - but I've never used `atexit` so I'm not really sure.

Comment: What would go in dates.ini? If I just start it up then it comes up with a KeyError for 'Dates'

Comment: Yup, you are right - I didn't catch that. I'll edit my answer. I'm not at home to test it, but that should fix it.

Comment: Ok so, it works now but it returns the value as a negative and it minuses 1 off of the final value. So if I change the date in dates.ini to 7 days ago the program will output the number -8 instead of a positive 7. I'm quite new to python which is why I can't figure out what's wrong myself

Comment: either `print((last - datetime.today()).days + 1)` or `print((datetime.today()).days - last - 1)`